# I need help assigning the output from a JS Json result to a variable and displaying it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

Here is what I have so far. I want to put the result in a variable, which then I will work with. I would also like to display the result/variable on a webpage. How can I do this?

```
<button onclick="function startRefresh()">Get Rates</button>

<script>
$(function () {
    startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh, 10000);
    var turl = 'https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker';
    var results = $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(turl) + '%22&format=json', function (data) {
        jQuery('#ticker').html(data['query'].results.ticker.last);
        jQuery('#ticker').append(' USD');
    });

}

document.write(results)
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you want to do with the result ?

Comment: First I just want to display it on the website, then I will do what I want with it via CSS.  I'm trying to make a widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $("#load-button").click(function(){
        startRefresh();
    });
});

function startRefresh() {
    //alert("hi");
    //setTimeout(startRefresh, 10000);
    var turl = 'https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker';
    var results = $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(turl) + '%22&format=json', function (data) {
        var result = data.query.results.ticker;
        var html = "";
        for(var key in result){
            html += '<p>' + key + ' = ' + result[key] + '</p><br>';
        }
        $("#mydiv").html(html);
    });

}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/4PkJq/4/)

Comment: Yes, what I want is to display the result section of that code. The JS works, I just don't know how to display that result, in HTML.

Comment: I have displayed it inside a div. And also added the load button

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but maybe this:

```
<button onclick="startRefresh()">Get Rates</button>

<script>
$(function () {
    startRefresh();
});

function startRefresh() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh, 10000);
    var turl = 'https://btc-e.com/api/2/ltc_usd/ticker';
    $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(turl) + '%22&format=json', function (data) {
        jQuery('#ticker').html(data['query'].results.ticker.last);
        jQuery('#ticker').append(' USD');
    });

}

</script>

<span>

<div id="ticker"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll be more clear sorry. When I press the button, I want it to run the startRefresh() function, and then display the result from the json/jQuery code as text.  I was thinking I need to add the results to a variable and then display the variable, but I am really new to Javascript.

Comment: edited my original code.  this would set the output div's contents to whatever the jquery get returned.  also your button click code was wrong